# Apache reverse proxy by HTTP/2 will lost MIME-type and use default

Tags: apache, proxy, http2

English is not my native language, please excuse typing errors.

I configure Apache reverse proxy as follow, and it works fire.

```
ProxyRequests Off
SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On

ProxyPass / https://example.com/
ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com/
```

And my website (PHP) support `HTTP/2`, so I want to proxy it by `HTTP/2`.

I enable `mod_proxy`, `mod_proxy_http`, `mod_ssl`, `mod_http2`, `mod_proxy_http2` and others some modules. And set `.php` MIME-type as `application/x-httpd-php`.

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

VirtualHost is follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/wwwroot/"
    ServerName localhost:443

    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On

    ProxyPass / h2://example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com/

    # Cert
    SSLCertificateFile ...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The different is `ProxyPass / https://example.com/` to `ProxyPass / h2://example.com/`.

**Response header `Content-Type` in Browser always get default MIME-type.**

You can find example at [phpMyAdmin Demo](https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/), filter `whitelist.php` in DevTools, this file `Content-Type` is `text/javascript`.

Proxy it by `HTTP/2`, the `Content-Type`
become `application/x-httpd-php`, it lost source MIME-type `text/javascript`.

And proxy it by `HTTP/1.1`, it works well.

How can I reslove this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It’s an old question but I ran with same problem and decide to investigate.

I found a [bug in http2 proxy](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66391).

It will be fixed in next `HTTPD` release (2.4.55)

Answer (score -1):

**Virtual Host file configuration:**

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ssl_certificate .....
    ssl_certificate_key ..........

  ProxyRequests Off Order deny, allow Allow from all
 <Location />
        ProxyPass http://example.com:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://example.com:8000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Next we need to enable a few Apache modules. To do this, issue the following commands:**

sudo a2enmod proxy

sudo a2enmod proxy_http

sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer

sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests

**Apache will now need to be restarted with the command:**

sudo service apache2 restart